# Formatting edit text text with two way binding

Tags: android, android-databinding

I am using two way binding for edit text text property like below

> android:text="@={model.price}"

Then in the model class I am doing the following:

```
public class CreateCourse extends BaseObservable {

 private String price = "";

@Bindable
public String getPrice() {
    return "$ " + price;
}

public void setPrice(String price) {

    if(this.price != price)
    {
        this.price = price;

        notifyPropertyChanged(BR.price);
        enableButton();
     }
  }
}
```

This is creating a kind of infinite loop and I am having infinite $ in my edit text as I open the screen.

So if this is not working how can we format edit text string with two way binding

Comment: May be because you append `'$'` with your price which is why `if(this.price != price)` is always **true**. Try this : `if(("$ "+ this.price) != price)`

Comment: even using that is causing the same issue

Comment: Okay, can you try with this condition : `if (!price.contains(this.price))` also make sure that you don't recursively set '$' by this line : `this.price = price;`

Comment: price.contains(this.price) is always true so it is never setting the property

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This worked for me:

> private String price = "$ ";

and then in the setter method:

```
public void setPrice(String price) {

    if(!this.price.equals(price))
    {
        if(price.isEmpty())
            this.price = "$ ";
        else
        this.price = price;

        notifyPropertyChanged(BR.price);
        enableButton();
      }
    }
```

Comment: although it does always set a $ sign but nothing stops the user to move the cursor before the dollar sign and start typing before the dollar sign. Which is not a good experience.